# Spark structure streaming write operations into couchbase?

Tags: apache-spark, couchbase, spark-structured-streaming

I have tried write data into couchbase using structure streaming, i referred spark connector 2.0, i declared couchbase connection in spark session, But am not able to connect with cocuhbase,below examble i tried , Any help will be appreciate thanks in advance

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("couch")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.couchbase.nodes", "127.0.0.1") 
  .config("spark.couchbase.bucket.mybucket", "123") 
  .config("com.couchbase.username", "Administrator")
  .config("com.couchbase.password", "password")
  .getOrCreate()

Dataset<row> df=....//dataset reading data from kafka

StreamingQuery query = df.writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "mycheckpointlocation")
  .option("idField", "value")
  .format("com.couchbase.spark.sql")
  .start();

query.awaitTermination();
```

Comment: Is there an error message/exception/log/etc?

Comment: @MatthewGroves connection itself its not established..!!

Comment: @MatthewGroves is there any sink connector like mongo,jdbc options are there in spark connector..

Comment: You probably don't need to provide the password "123" to "mybucket": bucket-level passwords have gone as of Couchbase Server 5.0 and above.  You can leave that second parameter as a blank "" field instead.  Have you read the most recent version of the Spark docs here?  https://docs.couchbase.com/spark-connector/2.4/getting-started.html

Comment: @GrahamPople Actually i tried this code only, but as your comment i tried but still no luck [link] (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.5/connectors/spark-2.1/structured-streaming.html)

Comment: Are you able to create a connection to the cluster using the standard SDKs, outside of Spark?  E.g. could you create a tiny sample program that just connects to the cluster and does a single KV op, using either the new alpha Scala SDK (https://docs.couchbase.com/scala-sdk/1.0/start-using-sdk.html) or the Java SDK (https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/start-using-sdk.html).  Just to troubleshoot...

Comment: @GrahamPople using java SDK am able to write docs into couchbase, but through spark it was not working..!!

Comment: I see.  What error do you get exactly?  Could use a stacktrace.